# MongoDB Pymongo and python versions mixup

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've previously worked with mongodb using nodejs, mongoose and mongdb compass. I wanted to get a hold of doing the same with Python. I'm trying to install pymongo, and it seems that using pip install has led to the package getting installed in the v2.7 part of my computer and the version 3.7 isn't able to import it. 
And everytime i run pip i get an error for the deprecation warning as so:

```
rahultandon$ pip install pymongo
```

OR

`rahultandon$ python -m pip install pymongo`

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
```

[I was following this tutorial](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-mongodb-and-python/) and then jumped to this https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb as link was given in the tutorial itself.

Whenever I run mongod the process ends with the following last 3 lines:

```
    2019-12-12T06:35:47.607+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2019-12-12T06:35:47.607+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-12-12T06:35:47.607+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

I'd really appreciate some help.

Comment: "and the version 3.7 isn't able to import it" which version are you talking about? python version or pymongo version?

Comment: python version.

Comment: I solved the problem. I was writing python and not python3 which makes all the difference. Interestingly, in the Python 3 folder on my laptop I found a readme.rtf which talked of using 'pip3' and 'idle3' which was really new to me. "Python 3 and Python 2 Co-existence

Python.org Python 3.7 and 2.7.x versions can both be installed on your system and will not conflict. Command names for Python 3 contain a 3 in them, python3 (or python3.7), idle3 (or idle3.7), pip3 (or pip3.7), etc.  Python 2.7 command names contain a 2 or no digit: python2 (or python2.7 or python), idle2 (or idle2.7 or idle)